# "be responsive to" VS "be adaptive to" VS "be receptive to"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. Americans are **receptive** to change.
> 2. Americans are **adaptive** to change.
> 3. Americans are **responsive** to change.

I am sorry for only providing a single line without any background. My question is is there any disparities between the three sentences.

Comment: I don't see much difference. I think all three statements are oxymorons. :-)

Comment: @RossMurray  That's rather unfair.  We Americans are very receptive to change, as long as it's not *climate* change.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a translation dictionary to check the meanings of these words, or an English language dictionary?   There is considerable difference between these three:

> **[receptive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/receptive)** (adj): Willing to consider or accept new suggestions and ideas.
>
> **[adapt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adapt)** (v): 1.1 Become adjusted to new conditions (adaptive = "able to easily adjust to new conditions")
>
> **[responsive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/responsive)**: Responding readily and with interest.

Examples:

> The CEO initially seemed **receptive** to the proposed changes in marketing strategy, as she agreed a new approach was needed, but in the end she had too many reservations about the cost to approve it.
>
> The CEO proved to be **adaptive** to changing market conditions, as she quickly increased production of popular products, and axed the development of products with poor sales.
>
> The CEO was praised for being **responsive** during the recent crisis, frequently taking time to answer the questions of employees concerned about the financial health of the company.